# Novel set during Roman era with main protagonist is a werewolf

Tags: story-identification, books, werewolf

I read this novel in paperback around 2002 in the UK, I bought it new then so it was in print in the early 2000s.

The novel was set in Roman times, but I cannot recall during which period or Emperor. I think it involved Roman Britain so at least Hadrian and possibly Antoninus Pius.

The main character was male and, I believe, a werewolf. He was not Roman, but wasn't actively against them. As I recall the character, he was focused on his own life/mission and only came into conflict with the Romans when they got in his way.

The cover was predominantly black with a man's face and a wolf's face (head?).

It is very hard to search for anything using the above in Google that doesn't result in you receiving results solely about romance novels!

Comment: There's a surprising amount of fiction combining "ancient Rome" and "werewolves". Like [this](https://www.amazon.com/Silver-Wolf-Legends-Wolves-Book-ebook/dp/B000FBJEGA) (but the werewolf protagonist is a woman) and [this](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9683241-wolf-blood) (but the werewolf is more involved with the Romans) and [this](https://bleedingcool.com/comics/recent-updates/empire-wolf-inspired-ancient-roman-legend-interview-creative-team/) (but it's a comic). I haven't found anything that quite fits your description yet.

Comment: The first link was to the first book in the series, so you were close!

Comment: Minus fif[teen wolf](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090142/)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could this be [*Night of the Wolf*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?19878) (1998) by Alice Borchardt?  This is the paperback U.K. cover, published in 2000:

[image: Cover of "Night of the Wolf" showing a wolf's head in the foreground, grey on black with a man's head above and right and the full moon above and left]

The [summary on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/258658.Night_of_the_Wolf) says:

> The fearsome legions of Julius Caesar have crushed resistance to Roman rule. Watching the tragic aftermath through yellow eyes afire with curiosity and intelligence is Maeniel, a gray wolf... and a shapeshifter unaware of his preternatural duality. But a new Maeniel is about to be born from the ruins.
>
> The sight of the beautiful Imona fills Maeniel with unfamiliar feelings and desires, triggering his transformation from wolf to man. In her arms he learns what it means to love. It is a knowledge that will change him forever. When Imona vanishes, Maeniel follows her trail--unaware that he is being pursued by a warrior-woman sworn to kill him. But the hunt upon which the two adversaries embark will lead them farther than they can imagine: to the gates of Rome itself--to the gates of their very souls...

So the story at least includes Gaul, but it's not clear from the summary if it extends into Brittania or not, though it's definitely in the right time period.

Comment: That's it - sounds a bit like romance from the description. I'll re-read it and see!

Comment: Ann Rice's sister wrote about werewolves? (Notice her sister endorsed.)